# Remove Shipping Information and Shipping method?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to remove Shipping Information and Shipping method in onepage checkout.

I followed this link for removing shipping information and shipping method `http://www.justwebdevelopment.com/blog/removed-shipping-address-and-shipping-method-from-onepage-checkout-in-magento/`

After that i have different type of payment in mysite all payment method it's not appear

Comment: can you please anyone suggest how to remove Shipping information and Shipping method from checkout page

Comment: Ok i will check this